# meaning of the phrase "get something locked in" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/pjzASrm_db0). It is at around 6 minute and 58 second. Here is the context:

> But if you are somebody that knows that you are overweight and need to lose body fat, start with nutrition, stick with nutrition, **get it locked** **in** and then start looking for other things from there.

I looked up what the phrasal verb [lock in](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lock-in) means, but still struggle to get what exactly the coach means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have something *locked in* it means that it's definite and fixed, so that you have no worries it will go away.

The phrase most commonly appears in things like negotiations or contracts, where you might *lock in* certain conditions as part of the deal.  For example a manufacturer might *lock in* a vendor of one of their key components, to ensure a steady supply.

Apparently it has since expanded to other subjects, but it means the same thing.  The writer recommends you definitely, *without fail*, stick to a particular nutrition plan, and then add on other things.

Answer (score 7):

To be "locked in" there means to be well-established as a regular routine or regimen.  Develop a nutritious diet and "stick to it", that is, do not deviate from it or lapse  into the earlier bad eating habits.

Answer (score 0):

Locked in could also refer to a person who has his future secured. No matter how free and alive you might feel,  your future destiny  is secured.   Locked in.